# how to check ip address for hotspot device - adb connect

Tags: android

i always turn on my hotspot from my device ( physical device ) and my laptop has connected.

i would describe before , My physical device have updated os version then the gateway is always change on every day, before its always start from 1. for example : `192.168.43.1`.
but now my device `192.168.x.x` ***where the x always change on every day***.

so in here i need some trick to know what my device ip ***without open android studio*** adb plugin on sidebar to check ( in android studio adb plugin can list device with ip address ) . because i coding on vscode, when i need to connect, i just run `adb connect 192.168.x.x:5555`

now i always open android studio to check, in setting device i didnt found what my own ip.

Answer (score 0):

This adb command will print the address for wlan0, which is typically the name of the wifi network interface:

```
adb shell ip addr show wlan0
```

typical output will be:

```
> 10: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state
> UP group default qlen 3000
>     link/ether 86:c3:99:76:d0:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     inet 192.168.1.102/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>     inet6 fe80::5e83:c045:895e:a001/64 scope link stable-privacy 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

where `192.168.1.102` is the local network ip address